# Ruby access hash element

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following hash:

```
{"title"=>"ga:browser=Firefox", "dimensions"=>[{:browser=>"Firefox"}], "metrics"=>[{:pageviews=>25474}], "id"=>"http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:3906565&amp;ga:browser=Firefox&amp;start-date=2010-02-06&amp;end-date=2011-02-06", "updated"=>#<DateTime: 212163710400001/86400000,-1/3,2299161>}
```

How would I print the value of pageviews?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you have a hashmap (not an array) which maps the key `"metrics"` to an array. That array contains a hash as its only element. And that hash maps the key `:pageviews` to the value `25474`. So to get that value you can do:

```
the_hash["metrics"][0][:pageviews]
```

This assumes that the hash with the `:pageviews` key will always be at position 0 in the array, which the key `"metrics"` is mapped to.

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to tell if it is a hashmap or array? or can you just tell by the structure?

Comment: @Tom: A hashmap is surrounded by curly braces and an array by square brackets. Also if a hash is not empty it contains key-value pairs in the form `key => value`, while an array only contains single values (of course those might themselves be arrays or hashes).

Comment: You can ask Ruby what it is by using `variablename.class`, where "variablename" is some variable you want to know about. For instance, `variable = {}; puts variable.class` will output "Hash" or `variable = []; puts variable.class` will output "Array".