# Value inside hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have some problems with a hash:

```
"commissions"=>
  {"commission"=>
    {"commissionID"=>"38767647",
     "date"=>"2014-09-22",
     "publisherID"=>"46272",
     "domainID"=>"1173659",
     "merchantID"=>"35216",
     "commissionValue"=>110,
     "orderValue"=>2095,
     "currency"=>"USD",
     "url"=>"http://www.asos.com"},
   "commission5"=>
    {
     other params
     }
```

How can I get the value of 'commissionValue'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby access hash element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910621/ruby-access-hash-element)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Ruby hash variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194219/access-ruby-hash-variables)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of nested hashes in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544858/accessing-elements-of-nested-hashes-in-ruby)

Comment: When you supply data, such as what should be a hash definition, it's really important to make sure it's a valid definition, otherwise we have to figure out first whether that's the problem. Please take the time to format it for readability also, as that helps us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) to get value of the hash by key.

```
h = {"commissions"=>
  {"commission"=>
    {"commissionID"=>"38767647",
      "date"=>"2014-09-22",
      "publisherID"=>"46272",
      "domainID"=>"1173659",
      "merchantID"=>"35216",
      "commissionValue"=>110,
      "orderValue"=>2095,
      "currency"=>"USD",
      "url"=>"http://www.asos.com"},
      "commission5"=> { }
  }
}
h["commissions"]["commission"]["commissionValue"]
# => 110
```